# is it possible to apply some condition to geojson file/layer before uploading on google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gis, geojson, google-datalayer

i have a geojson file having some data. i can load this file on google map successfully. But actually i want to filter it before showing on google map that is to locate only those points on google map from geojson which fulfilling some condition

```
testLayer = new google.maps.Data();
 testLayer.loadGeoJson('geojson/file/path/test.geojson');
   testLayer.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's supported by [Google Maps Data API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer), the following example demonstrates how to clear two polygons (letter `o` in `Google` word)

```js
$(function () {
    initMap();
});


function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('div_map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -25.0323575,
            lng: 115.2244976
        },
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });


    var layer = new google.maps.Data();
    layer.addListener('addfeature', processData);
    layer.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
    layer.setMap(map);
   
}

function processData(o) {
    var f = o.feature;
    var geometry = f.getGeometry();
    
    
    if(o.feature.getProperty('letter') == "o"){
        o.feature.setGeometry(null);
    }
}
```

```css
#div_map {
    height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_map"></div>
```